# Script from external file still firing even if the element is empty

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I have 2 html files

```
 1. main.html
 2. external.html - contains script tag
```

external content will be loaded to main.html once a user click the button using jquery.load function

Now my problem is if the user click twice the load button, the functions inside the external.html fires twice also even if i emptied the div element in main.html

i tried

```
empty()
```

and

```
html("")
```

functions to clear out the content of the div but still no luck.

this is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/XLZGquoebTTHahgJWNOk?p=preview

main.html (code below)

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <input type='button' id='btn_load' value='Load External Content' />

        <br /><p id="loading" style="display:none;" >Loading Data, Please wait...</p>

        <div id="page_content">

        </div>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).on('click','#btn_load',function(){  

            $('#loading').show();

            $('#page_content').html("");
            $('#page_content').empty();
            $('#script_external').remove();

            $('#page_content').load('external.html',function(){
              $('#loading').hide();
            });

        }); 
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

external.html (code below)

```
<h3>External Data</h3>

<input type='button' id='btn_clickme' value='Click Me' />

<script id='script_external'>
   $(document).on('click','#btn_clickme',function(){
      alert("This msg is from external file");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Solved: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/script-from-external-file-still-firing-even-if-the-element-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

You should use off() before re-bind a new events http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Hi Ocrenaka, i tried  `$('#btn_clickme').off();` on main and external html but didn't work,